# How to get database table header information into an CSV File

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to connect to the database and get current state of a table and update that information into csv file, with below mentioned piece of code, am able to get data information into csv file but am not able to get header information from database table into csv file.

So my questions is **How can I get Database Table Header information into an CSV File ?**

```
$config['database'] = 'sakila';
$config['host'] = 'localhost';
$config['username'] = 'root';
$config['password'] = '';

$d = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$config['database'].';host='.$config['host'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM actor";
$stmt = $d->prepare($query);

// Execute the statement
$stmt->execute();

var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$data = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "Hi";
    // Export every row to a file
    fputcsv($data, $row);
}
```

Header information meaning:

```
Vehicle     Build   Model
 car        2009    Toyota
 jeep       2007    Mahindra
```

So header information for this would be **Vehicle Build Model**

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just get the keys from the array $row: [array_keys()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php). Now you have all the columnnames and you can put them in your csv-file.

======= EDIT =======

```
<?php

$header = array();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if(empty($header)){ // do it only once!
      $header = array_keys($row); // get the columnnames
      fputcsv($data, $header); // put them in csv
    }

    echo "Hi";
    // Export every row to a file
    fputcsv($data, $row);
}
?>
```

Comment: Would appreciate if you can you explain this in little detail as I am not getting it right now.

Comment: @Frank: How would it know if it is an header or not ?

Comment: @Frank: This approach worked but I am not sure what is happening with header, can you explain as to how this would work in details, possibly via comments so that I can get better understanding of it so that I can learn from it.

Comment: Rachel, the function array_keys() gets all the keys from the array $row. In my example, array_keys() fills the array $header and this array is writen in your csv. Because of the if{}, this is done only once. See also the hyperlink to the PHP-manual.

Comment: @Frank: Thank you Frank, now I understood it. Appreciate your guidance with it.

Answer (score 2):

Using SHOW COLUMNS FROM  will get you the column names from . You then can write the first line of your CSV with them:

```
// Do this before adding the rows from the database
$query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM some_table";
$stmt = $d->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$columns = '';
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $columns .= $row['Field'] . ',';
}
$columns = substr($columns, 0, -1);
fputcsv($data, $columns);
```

Comment: Can you explain as how can I write first line of CSV file with them, coz right now it is not being updated into CSV file ?

Comment: Yes. I am going through it right now, thanks for detailed explanation.

Comment: No need for an extra query, just get the information from the array $row

Answer (score 1):

Use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html):

```
mysqldump -u user -p --fields-terminated-by=',' --tab=/tmp mydatabase mytable
```

The above command will create 2 files in /tmp. mytable.sql and mytable.txt. The sql file will contain the table creation schema and the txt file will contain the records of the mytable table with fields delimited by a comma.

Comment: it only created .sql file and not .txt file, am I missing out something here.

Answer (score 0):

You already have it in [PDO::FETCH_ASSOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php): returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set

EDIT:
One way to get and write the names of columns is (put it before your while lopp)

```
fputcsv($data, array_keys($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)));
```

Read about [php arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and associative arrays in particular and on function on arrays (such as array_keys). Answers to particular questions can not replace understanding of basic concepts such as arrays.

Comment: Than how do I get that header information out, am not sure as to how we can work with database header information.